# How to load JSON array from file NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How should you load JSON array from file in NodeJS?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.json', (err, fileContent) => {
    if( err ) {
    } else {
      data = JSON.parse(fileContent);
      console.log(fileContent);
    }
})
```

input.json

```
[
{ "date": "2017-02-18" },
{ "date": "2017-02-18" },
]
```

Getting error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position

Comment: remove the last `,`. that makes it invalid JSON.

Comment: Note that you can  `require` a JSON file. `require` loads and parses it as JSON!

Comment: @DanielA.White now console logs <Buffer 5b 0d 0a 7b 20 22 64 61 74 65 22 3a 20 22 32 30 31 36 2d 30 31 2d 30 35 22 2c 20 22 75 73 65 72 5f 69 64 22 3a 20 31 2c 20 22 75 73 65 72 5f 74 79 70 ... >  shouldn't it log array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update input.json it contains one extra comma(**,**) at the end before closing bracket (**]**)

```
[
{ "date": "2017-02-18" },
{ "date": "2017-02-18" }
]
```

and If you are reading **json** file in node.js and want to show data in json then place **UTF8** while reading the file

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.json', 'utf8',(err, fileContent) => {
    if( err ) {
    } else {
      data = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
      console.log(fileContent);
      console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Comment: See your input.json and check mine and compare it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure JSON is valid. ie, no trailing commas.

If you are loading something like a configuration,
simply `const data = require('./json-file.json')`.

node can simply require json files natively. however this is synchronous. So only use it for something like loading a config in start-up.